Why does my nested progress bar not display during long-running command?
I have 4 nested foreach loops with Write-Progress statements within.  Prior to each nested loop I want to display a preliminary message within a progress bar to notify user the script is about to run a long-running command next.
Once the command returns, I loop through the items and update the previous progress bar with actual item details.
I'm having issues with the first call to the 3rd progress bar, Write-Progress @itemProgressParams which never displays "Getting items". Once the items are obtained, that progress bar properly displays while looping through them.
The similar calls on the 2nd progress bar properly displays both the preliminary message and then updates accordingly.
Why wouldn't the 3rd progress bar do the same?  This is driving me batty.
Context:  I'm looping through Azure subscriptions, Recovery Services Vaults, Backup Containers, and Backup items.
The expected sample behavior:
Subscription [Subscription1 (1 of ##)           ]  # displays
    Recovery Vault [Getting vaults ...          ]  # displays

Subscription [Subscription1 (1 of ##)           ]  # displays
    Recovery Vault [Vault1 (1 of ##)            ]  # displays
        Backup Container [Container1 (1 of ##)  ]  # displays
            Backup Item [Getting items ...      ]  ### does not display

Subscription [Subscription1 (1 of ##)           ]  # displays
    Recovery Vault [Vault1 (1 of ##)            ]  # displays
        Backup Container [Container1 (1 of ##)  ]  # displays
            Backup Item [Item1 (1 of ##)        ]  # displays

Subscription [Subscription1 (1 of x)            ]  # displays
    Recovery Vault [Vault1 (1 of y)             ]  # displays
        Backup Container [Container2 (2 of ##)  ]  # displays
            Backup Item [Getting items ...      ]  ### does not display

Subscription [Subscription1 (1 of ##)           ]  # displays
    Recovery Vault [Vault1 (1 of ##)            ]  # displays
        Backup Container [Container2 (2 of ##)  ]  # displays
            Backup Item [Item1 (1 of ##)        ]  # displays

Subscription [Subscription1 (1 of ##)           ]  # displays
    Recovery Vault [Vault1 (1 of ##)            ]  # displays
        Backup Container [Container2 (2 of ##)  ]  # displays
            Backup Item [Item2 (2 of ##)        ]  # displays

Code excerpt:
foreach ($subscriptionName in $subscriptions) {
    $subscriptionLoopCounter++
    $subscriptionProgressParams = @{
        PercentComplete = ($subscriptionLoopCounter / $totalSubscriptions) * 100
        Activity        = "Subscription"
        Status          = "$subscriptionName ($subscriptionLoopCounter of $totalSubscriptions)"
        Id              = 0
    }
    Write-Progress @subscriptionProgressParams  ###<-- properly displays###
        
    $subscription = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName
    
    $rsvProgressParams = @{
        PercentComplete = 0
        Activity        = "Recovery Vault"
        Status          = "Getting vaults ..."
        Id              = 1
        ParentId        = 0
    }
    Write-Progress @rsvProgressParams  ###<-- properly displays###
    
    # Get all recovery services vaults in subscription
    $recoveryServicesVaults = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault

    $totalRsvs = $recoveryServicesVaults.count
    $rsvLoopCounter = 0
    foreach ($rsv in $recoveryServicesVaults) {
        $rsvLoopCounter++
        $rsvProgressParams = @{
            PercentComplete = ($rsvLoopCounter / $totalRsvs) * 100
            Activity        = "Recovery Vault"
            Status          = "$($rsv.Name) ($rsvLoopCounter of $totalRsvs)"
            Id              = 1
            ParentId        = 0
        }
        Write-Progress @rsvProgressParams  ###<-- properly displays###
        
        $backupContainers = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVM -VaultId $rsv.Id | Sort-Object FriendlyName
        
        # Calculate total number of backup containers across all vaults for progress
        $totalBackupContainers = $backupContainers.Count
        $backupContainerCounter = 0
        foreach ( $backupContainer in $backupContainers ) {
            $backupContainerCounter++
            # Update the progress bar for backup containers
            $containerProgressParams = @{
                PercentComplete = ($backupContainerCounter / $totalBackupContainers) * 100
                Activity        = "Backup Container"
                Status          = "$($backupContainer.FriendlyName) ($backupContainerCounter of $totalBackupContainers)"
                Id              = 2
                ParentId        = 1
            }
            Write-Progress @containerProgressParams  ###<-- properly displays###
            
            $itemProgressParams = @{
                PercentComplete = 0
                Activity    = "Backup Item  "
                Status      = "Getting items ..."
                Id              = 3
                ParentId        = 2
            }
            Write-Progress @itemProgressParams  ###<-- Does not display!!###
            
            $backupItems = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $backupContainer -WorkloadType AzureVM


            $totalBackupItems = $backupItems.Count
            $itemLoopCounter = 0
            foreach ( $backupItem in $backupItems ) {
                $itemLoopCounter++
                $itemProgressParams = @{
                    PercentComplete = ($itemLoopCounter / $totalBackupItems) * 100
                    Activity        = "Backup Item"
                    Status          = "$(($backupItem.SourceResourceId -split "/")[-1]) ($itemLoopCounter of $totalBackupItems)"
                    Id              = 3
                    ParentId        = 2
                }
                Write-Progress @itemProgressParams  ###<-- properly displays###
                       
                #... rest of code snipped...
            }
        }
    }
}
                

